# launchctl starts program but does not list pid

Tags: macos, process, webserver, launchctl

I have been troubleshooting this issue for a while now. Consulted the web, several stackexchange platforms and discussion forums. Here is my problem description:

**Usecase:**

I have naviserver installed on a mac os x el capitan 10.11.6

Instead of calling

```
/usr/local/ns/bin/nsd -f -u nsadmin -g nsadmin -t /usr/local/ns/conf/nsd-config.tcl
```

to start the server and a kill command to stop the server I would like to manage it through a LaunchDaemon.

**Problem Description:**

I can successfully start a LaunchDaemon through `launchctl`. However when looking at the `launchctl` list it lists the plist without a PID. I therefore need to stop the service manually via `kill` - instead I would like to be able to stop the service with `launchctl stop`.

**Question in essence:**

*Why doesn't launchctl list the PID of it's successfully started LaunchDaemon?*

**What I have tried so far**

1. Changing the plist file, minimizing parameters, no KeepAlive, no OnDemand, include Program parameter
2. Changing ownerships admin:wheel nsadmin:nsadmin admin:root
3. Running as LaunchAgent via /Library/LaunchAgents directory

**Here is what I have done:**

I have the following plist under `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.naviserver.dev01.plist`

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC “-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN” “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd”>
       <plist version=“1.0”>
          <dict>
           <key>Label</key>
               <string>org.naviserver.dev01</string>

               <key>ProgramArguments</key>
           <array>
                   <string>/usr/local/ns/bin/nsd</string>
                   <string>-u</string>
                   <string>nsadmin</string>
                   <string>-g</string>
                   <string>nsadmin</string>
                   <string>-t</string>
                   <string>/usr/local/ns/conf/nsd-config.tcl</string>
           </array>

           <key>StandardOutPath</key>
               <string>/usr/local/var/log/naviserver_daemon.log</string>

           <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
               <string>/usr/local/var/log/naviserver_daemon.log</string>
       </dict>
    </plist>
```

The following privileges and ownerships apply

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  857 Aug 11 15:03 org.naviserver.dev01.plist
```

Starting the service works

```
sudo launchctl load org.naviserver.dev01.plist
sudo launchctl start org.naviserver.dev01
```

However the launchctl list does not show the service’s PID

```
sudo launchctl list | grep naviserver
-   0   org.naviserver.dev01
```

I can find the running process via

```
ps -ax | grep nsd
```

Currently I am always manually restarting the server through a `kill` via the PID, which isn’t nice. I’d like to manage this through `launchctl` which works with starting the process but not with stopping it again.

Has anyone else run into this problem and is there anything obviously wrong with my approach, which I can change to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've left the `-f` (foreground) flag out of the `ProgramArguments` array. Without that, naviserver re-runs itself in the background and then exits, meaning that launchd doesn't know the PID of the (backgrounded) server process.

Comment: Oh my! Thank you very much for pointing this out - it solved the issue. Thanks!